# Como determinar o número de arestas do radarchart?

Tags: javascript, html5, css3, canvas, chartjs

Estou usando [RadarChart](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#radar-chart) do [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org).
Tenho [esse Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jdnosje5/) funcionando.

Vejam que neste exemplo o gráfico é montado dinamicamente de acordo com os dados inseridos. 

Bem, mas eu gostaria de determinar a quantidade de arestas geradas, independente dos valores, ou seja, ao invés das 4 arestas que foram geradas no Fiddle, eu gostaria de 10 arestas. O resultado ficaria como na imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Além das arestas, existe alguma forma de acrescentar legenda tanto para as linhas quanto para os itens no gráfico?


Apesar da documentação e [outras configurações](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#getting-started-global-chart-configuration) disponíveis, infelizmente não sou tão bom em inglês, e mesmo usando o Translate e fazendo tentativa e erro não consegui obter o resultado tão requerido.

 Salve Stackoverflow em Português!

 Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui tudo [nesse Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jedarc/y4trpr15/). Tentativa e erro.

Segue o código completo:

```js
var radarChartData = {
  labels: ["Eating", "Drinking", "Sleeping", "Designing"],
    datasets: [
   {
    label: "My First dataset",
    fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0)",
    strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
    pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
    pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
    pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
    pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
    data: [2,2,2,2]
   },
   {
    label: "My Second dataset",
    fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0)",
    strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
    pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
    pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
    pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
    pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
    data: [8,8,8,8]
   }
  ]
 };

 window.myRadar = new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d")).Radar(radarChartData, {
            responsive: true,
        //scaleShowLabels : true,
        animationSteps: 80,
        animationEasing: "easeOutQuart",
        scaleOverride: true,
        scaleSteps: 10,
        scaleStepWidth: 1,
        scaleStartValue: 0,
        angleShowLineOut : false,
        scaleLineColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)",
        
        legendTemplate : '<% for (var i=0; i<datasets.length; i++) { %>'
                    +'<h3 style=\"color:<%=datasets[i].strokeColor%>\">.'
                    +'<% if (datasets[i].label) { %><%= datasets[i].label %><% }%>'
                +'<% } %></h3>'
        });

document.getElementById("legendDiv").innerHTML = window.myRadar.generateLegend();
```

```css
#canvas-container {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
    }

    canvas {
        display: inline;
    }
```

```html
<script src="http://www.chartjs.org/assets/Chart.js"></script>
<div id="canvas-container">
            <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
        </div>
<div id="legendDiv"></div>
```

Para a maioria das opções, usei as [configurações globais](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#getting-started-global-chart-configuration).

Na questão de uma escala estática, basta mudar a opção `scaleOverride` que por padrão vem `false` para `true`, e isso te obrigará a especificar alguns outros valores, como `scaleSteps` (Até onde vai a sua escala? no meu caso 10, então `scaleSteps = 10`), `scaleStepWidth` (de quanto em quanto será incrementado, no meu caso 1 em 1), e por ultimo `scaleStartValue` que determina o valor de partida.

Para a legenda, me baseei [nessa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20397512/how-can-labels-legends-be-added-for-all-chart-types-in-chart-js-chartjs-org), onde apenas alterei no `legendTemplate` `lineColor` para `strokeColor`, pois o link em questão resolve o problema para outro tipo de gráfico.